# Python function or syntactic sugar to return all elements of a generator expression?

Tags: python, generator, lazy-evaluation, syntactic-sugar

Given a (finite) generator expression, I would like to make a single function call that returns all elements of the generator expression.

```
>>> a = (i for i in range(1,101))
>>> a
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x101873460>
>>> a.next()
1
>>> a.next()
2
```

In other words, I would like to avoid loops like:

```
for i in a:
    print i
```

and instead have a syntactic sugar for the loop:

```
a.all() # or the like
```

I looked at `itertools` but it wasn't clear to me that such a thing exists.

Comment: How do you deal with generator expressions that never end? i.e. 
`def my_gen():
     i = 0
     while True:
        i = i+1
        yield i
`

Comment: You don't. In the case I'm referring to, the generator is expression is finite.

Comment: Generator expression `a` could be any arbitrary type, not just a list; it could be tuple, dict, set, frozenset, or any other/ non-builtin type.

Answer (score 4):

You can just create a list out of it as:

```
list(a)
```

#### Example

```
a = (i for i in range(1,101))

print list(a)
[1, 2, 3, ..., 100]
```

Infact, since in this case you are getting the items into a list, you can also use list comprehension:

```
a = list(range(1, 101))
```

Now, `a` is a list instead of a generator object.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your last comment.  Why is `[i for i in range(1, 101)` simpler than `list(a)`? (Here, `list(range(1,101))`-- although since we're using Python 2, we wouldn't really need the list.)  You often see people write `[i for i in something_iterable]` when really they could simply write `list(something_iterable)`, and I think it's because they learned listcomps before seeing how `list` and `tuple` and `set` consume iterables.

Comment: Only if we know `a` is supposed to be a list. Generator expression `a` could be any arbitrary type, not just a list; it could be tuple, dict, set, frozenset, or any other/ non-builtin type.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is the best solution.

```
a = [i for i in range(1, 101)]
print a
[1, 2, 3, ..., 100]
```